# Convert .oxps file to .pdf file on Windows 8

Tags: conversion

I have done a university assignment and accidentally saved it as an .oxps file... How might I convert .oxps file to .pdf on Windows 8?

Comment: Use the same program you used to save it to save a new copy

Answer (score 6):

You can try to use online services such as:
http://online2pdf.com/oxps-to-pdf

You can also try installing a PDF printer on your PC, opening up the `.oxps` file and then "printing" to PDF.

PDF printer: [CutePDF](http://www.cutepdf.com/)

Comment: If your documents contain sensitive or personal information, however, an online service might not be the best option.

Comment: For sure, you should always exercise discretion when uploading data to 3rd parties.

Answer (score 6):

This can be done using [GhostXPS](http://ghostscript.com/download/gxpsdnld.html) (9.19 and above):

`gxpswin64-9.19.exe -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=pdffile.pdf -dNOPAUSE oxpsfile.oxps`

Change the name of the GhostXPS executable as appropriate.

---

## Batch file for easy conversion

```
@echo off

C:\path\to\ghostxps.exe  -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=%1.pdf -dNOPAUSE %1
```

Save as `oxps2pdf.bat` or similar.

Usage: `oxps2pdf INPUTFILE`

## Adding OXPS to PDF conversion to the context *(right-click)* menu

1. Start the Registry Editor:  run: `regedit.exe`
2. Navigate to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\SystemFileAssociations\`
3. locate `.oxps\` key , if it doesnt exist, create it *(right click --> New --> Key)*
4. locate `shell\` subkey, if it doesn't exist, create it
5. create `pdfconvert\` subkey *(name doesn't really matter)*
6. double click on the `(Default)` REG_SZ String to give the menu a name, i.e. *Convert to PDF*

[image: Regedit Command Description Definition]

7. create 'command` subkey
8. Define (Default) String to `"C:\path\to\gxpswin64.exe" -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=%1.pdf -dNOPAUSE %1`

[image: Regedit Command Definition]

9. Repeat the steps for `.xps` if you wish

Now you can see the new added context menu item **Convert To PDF**
[image: Context Menu Item Added ScreenShot]

## Adding OXPS to PDF conversion to the right-click menu (Send to)

As an alternative you can setup the **Send To** menu instead. This works, but is suboptimal.

1. Navigate to your SendTo folder (Win-R to show Run dialog; enter `shell:sendto`).
2. Inside the SendTo folder, create a shortcut to the `oxps2pdf.bat` batch file found above.
3. Rename the newly created shortcut "Convert OXPS to PDF".

Now, when you right-click on a file, the Send To menu should contain "Convert OXPS to PDF".

Comment: I wish I was able to give you two votes for: +1 for using a GPL solution; +1 (I wish) for the (pseudo) context menu solution. Great work!

Comment: Thanks! Glad to help. As for using free software, future GhostXPS releases should introduce OXPS to PDF conversion, meaning we won't have to rely on `xpsconverter.exe` at that point. [Details here](http://superuser.com/a/886495/99977).

Comment: OXPS-to-PDF conversion was introduced in GhostXPS 9.19 (released March 2016). I have edited my answer to reflect the simpler method that relies on GhostXPS only.