# oxps to pdf or image - Linux

Tags: linux, pdf, conversion, xps

I've been trying to solve the problem of converting an .oxps file to .pdf or other file format. Any solutions for Linux out there?

I've been searching around and cannot come up with much thus far.

Maybe even something to convert to xps first and then pdf?

---

I've tried ImageMagick's `convert` and `ghostscript`, but no luck. Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Note: I'm using Gentoo and/or Ubuntu.

---

**EDIT**

The solution is covered in the answer from @ThatGuy. However, for some reason, `mudraw` was not pulled in with `mupdf-tools` on ubuntu (I am running a headless 12.04.5 LTS ubuntu).

However, the source is available from [MuPDF's](http://mupdf.com) website. I built the source and was able to solve the problem.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Method #1 (recommended)

Software requirements: [Ghostscript/GhostXPS](https://ghostscript.com/download/) (version 9.19 or later).

To convert OXPS to PDF, simply execute the following command:

`gxps -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=/path/to/output.pdf -dNOPAUSE /path/to/input.oxps`

This method preserves text layers.

---

## Method #2 (deprecated)

*(This works on Windows, Mac, and Linux, but converts text layers to images)*

Use `mudraw` (included with [MuPDF](https://mupdf.com/downloads/); mupdf-tools on Debian-based distributions) to convert the .oxps file to a series of .png files (converting directly to PDF doesn't work properly; fonts get messed up) with a resolution of 300 dpi:

```
mudraw -o mudraw_output_page_number_%d.png -r 300 input.oxps
```

Convert the .png files to a multipage PDF using [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php)'s `convert` utility:

```
convert mudraw_output_page_number_*.png final.pdf
```

Note: If `convert` messes up the page order you can specify each individual .png file as the input (i.e., without using wildcards):

```
convert 1.png 2.png 3.png final.pdf
```

This should work on all platforms where MuPDF and ImageMagick are available (so on Windows, too).

Comment: Thanks, but no luck. Also, I'm not too familiar with Ubuntu, mainly Gentoo, mudraw was not pulled in when installing on Ubuntu...but was when I built it on Gentoo. However, no luck.

Comment: MuPDF is split into several packages on Debian-based distributions. ``mudraw`` is included in the mupdf-tools package. Could you elaborate on why it doesn't work?

Comment: I am getting these messages: `error: cannot recognize version maker`, `warning: trying to repair broken xref`, `warning: lexical error (unexpected ')')` and a bunch more like that.

Comment: According to http://www.mupdf.com/docs/browse/source/pdf/pdf-xref.c, that should be ``version marker``. Anyway, maybe try explicitly specifying the output format, like so: ``mudraw -o mudraw_output_page_number_%d.png -r 300 -F png input.oxps``

Comment: Also, which version of mudraw are you using (i.e., what is the output of ``apt-cache policy mupdf-tools``)?

Comment: On Ubuntu, I have `0.9-2ubuntu1`, but like I said, no mudraw was pulled in with it so I was not able to test on ubuntu. On Gentoo I have `1.1_p20121127`.

Comment: Ok. The version I used was old. I downloaded the source from [mupdf.com](http://mupdf.com) and all is well. Thanks for your help. I accepted your answer.

Comment: ``mudraw`` was called ``pdfdraw`` in earlier versions of MuPDF (including 0.9-2ubuntu1). Is ``pdfdraw`` installed on your system? If not, you can install it using ``sudo apt-get install mupdf-tools``. Now, I've never used ``pdfdraw`` myself, but you might be able to use ``pdfdraw`` instead of ``mudraw``.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this online converter - [online2pdf](https://online2pdf.com/oxps-to-pdf).

Or if you have access to a Windows 8 machine, you can convert the file to pdf(or xps) using a pdf printer.

Also, MuPDF on linux can open a .oxps file(only for viewing though).

Comment: Thanks. But I cannot use the online converter and no access to windows 8. Need something local. But a good answer for others who may come across.

Comment: Accepting this answer as seems the only way at this point in time. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, the .oxps format is a new format supported only in Windows 8 so only a few programs support it.

Comment: Thanks, I finally gave up on the linux route. Got someone with a windows 8 box to help out.

Answer (score 1):

In windos8 XPS printer is already installed. Open oxps file in xps viewer and click to print, choose Microsoft XPS Document writer, option will come to save to file and in the bottom file,s name OpenXPS Document (*.oxps) will appear, Do not choose it, go to down options will appear, choose XPS Document (*.xps).You will get Xps document to be convertrd in PDF by XPS to PDF converter available free from cnet.com

Comment: I believe the poster is looking for a Linux solution.

Answer (score 0):

In 2021, tested on debian 9 and using the mupdf-tools option (in tune with [ThatGuy's](https://superuser.com/users/99977/thatguy) [answer](https://superuser.com/a/886495/1263170), since the system still won't let me comment on his answer due to my reputation), with mutool version 1.9a the command would remain as follows:

```
mutool draw -o mudraw_output_page_number_% d.png -r 300 input.oxps
```

And later, if the imagemagick command would be kept

```
convert 1.png 2.png 3.png final.pdf
```

I hope it serves you.